Injectivity radius bound for a metric with bounded curvature on $\mathbb{R}^n$
My question is as follows:
Question: Is it true that if $g$ is a metric (need not be complete) on $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $B_g(x_0, 1)\subset \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and $g$ has bounded curvature on a unit ball
$$
\sup_{B_g(x_0, 1)} |\text{Rm}|_g \leq 1,
$$
then is it true that we can say that the injectivity radius at $x_0$ is uniformly bounded away from zero (not depending on the metric $g$)?
I know that it is not true in general that simply a bound on curvature implies a bound on the injectivity radius, because for example you can take a disconnected sum of countably Berger spheres which are collapsing (see this post for instance). But the hypothesis that $g$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ would rule out such examples.
To prove this, I was thinking that one could take a doubling of $B_g(x_0, 1)$, glue along its boundary in some way which has uniformly bounded curvature (not depending on $g$) which would give a metric $h$ on the 3-sphere $\mathbb{S}^3$ with uniformly bounded curvature say $|\text{Rm}|_h\leq 2$ and diameter bounded from below uniformly by say 1. Then I imagine some result for compact manifolds would give $\text{inj}_h\geq \alpha$ for some $\alpha>0$ independent of $h$, and thus a bound $\text{inj}_g(x_0)\geq \alpha$ which is independent of $g$.
Clearly the outline of a proof above is a little vague with some gaps that need to be filled in, but I was wondering if anyone had an different idea for a proof and/or a way to fill in the holes in my outline?

Why isn't the pullback on $\mathbb{R}^3$ of the Berger metrics $g_t$ on $\mathbb{S}^3$ by the stereographic projection be a counterexample to your statement ?

Wouldn't the requirement that $B_g(x, 1)\subset\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ still be an issue here? Any diffeomorphism $\phi: U\to V$ with $U\subset\mathbb{S}^3$ and $V\subset \mathbb{R}^3$ must necessarily have small diameter if the Berger metric on $\mathbb{S}^3$ has small injectivity radius and bounded curvature by 1. It doesn't seem clear to me that such a metric can be extended within $\mathbb{R}^3$ to have within it a ball of radius 1 contained with bounded curvature by 1

All Berger spheres have diameter at least π/2 (because the geodesic $p=(1,0)\in\mathbb{S}^3\subset\mathbb{C}^2$ and $q=(0,1)$ is orthogonal to the fibres of the Hopf fibration). Hence if you stereographic project $\phi:\mathbb{S}^3\backslash{q}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ then $B_g(p,1)$ will be compact and not contain $q$ hence your hypothesis will be satisfied for $\phi_*g$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$.
